# Export Data to CSV with Vietnamese

Tags: c#, export-to-csv, cultureinfo, culture

I am developing a website that allow to export data in MSSQL to a CSV file but i have a trouble that my Data Base contain Vietnamese so when i export it to CVS file. All of Vietnamese has error!
How could i do to export Vietnamese without error with Vietnamese data?
Here my return file code:

```
return File(new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(str.ToString()), "text/csv", filename + DateTime.Now + ".csv");
```

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679656/asp-net-excel-export-encoding-problem and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024776/export-different-language-content-in-csv-file-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28vs.71%29.aspx) class? Like this:

```
return File(new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(str.ToString( new CultureInfo("vi"))), "text/csv", filename + DateTime.Now + ".csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked.

> Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
>   Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());